# how to write soap header in soap client

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I have used Axis2 for the creation of stubs.

```
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-4" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>Uname</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwd</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

can anyone give me the java soap client code for the above header

Answer (score 0):

First link in Google for (adding soap header in axis2 example)

[Working with Custom SOAP Headers](http://wso2.com/library/3156/)